# Receiving error in dataloader delete attempt, "RHX_Sales_History: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded"

Tags: error

Trying to delete custom object Sales History records but receive the following error via dataloader output:
"RHX_Sales_History: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded"

records have a master-detail relationship with account, but have read/write privileges and I can manually delete in the system without issue.

I have downloaded the updated dataloader as well.

Comment: Sounds like there is code in your org that runs on the delete of that object. In the dataloader case you are deleting multiple records but interactively one record only. It is easy for [bad algorithms whose CPU usage grows exponentially with the number of records](https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/11/09/fixing-a-common-cause-of-system-limitexception-apex-cpu-time-limit-exceeded/) to be introduced. Examine your debug logs to see what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

RHX is the namespace of the [Rollup Helper app](https://sites.google.com/a/passagetech.com/spring-2015---rollup-helper/resources/frequently-asked-questions/common-issues-and-troubleshooting-steps).  Sounds like you have a rollup calc configured for Sales History.  You'll probably have to reduce the batch size in the Data Loader settings, but be careful that you don't consume too many API calls because of the reduction.  Divide the total number of records to be deleted by the batch size to estimate the API calls you'll need to do the deletion.

Comment: Can also ( if you have permissions ) use the bulk API as you will have more API calls allowed - but still need to be mindful of your limits and they reset every 24 hours.